# Use RegEx to remove all carriage returns and line feeds between two strings

Tags: regex

I am trying to match / find (for removal) all carriage return and line feed instances between 2 strings that are recurring within same file.

Example:

```
Reason for test
Body info random text line 1
Body info random text line 2
Pre-conditions Scenario

some random text in between some random text in between
some random text in between some random text in between

Reason for test
Body info random text line 3 
Body info random text line 4
Body info random text line 5
Pre-conditions Scenario
```

Would like to match on all of the carriage returns and line feeds between

- Header string:  "*Reason for test*"
  and
- Terminator string:     "*Pre-conditions Scenario*"

The number of *CR* and *LF* that I am trying to remove between these two strings change from one paragraph block to the other.  In example above there are 3 in first block, and there are 4 in the second block, etc...

The **ideal** result would be

```
Reason for test Body info random text line 1 Body info random text line 2
Pre-conditions Scenario

some random text in between some random text in between
some random text in between some random text in between

Reason for test Body info random text line 3 Body info random text line 4 Body info random text line 5
Pre-conditions Scenario
```

I have tried many variations, but have ended up stuck with the following Regular Expression using a Positive Lookbehind and Positive Lookahead group construct:

> > > `(?<=Reason for test)|$([\r\n])(?=Pre-conditions Scenario)/sgm`

However this syntax is only able to match / find **2** of the " **\r\n** " instances per block paragraph, regardless of how many "Body info" lines there are, between the header and terminating strings.

I've posted this scenario on a tool site here > [Sample RegEX builder](https://regex101.com/r/2NKZao/3)

Thanks in advance for all your feedback.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/2NKZao/4) what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the job:

- Find: `(Reason for test|\G).*?\K\R(?=(?:(?!Reason for test)[\s\S])*?\RPre-conditions Scenario)`
- Replace:  (a space)

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2NKZao/4)

Comment: Lovely! This was particularly helpful to my understanding of how `\G` can be used to advantage. Is there any particular reason you didn't make `(Reason for test|\G)` a non-capture group? The reason I ask is because when I see a capture group I assume it's needed for a back-reference or use in a replacement, that a non-capture group would be used if the contents were not needed. Also, can `.*?` not be just `.*`?

Comment: What about `(?:Reason for test|\G).*\K\R(?!Pre-conditions Scenario)`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VIeDHt/1/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yes, the capture group is useless. For the later point, I use a Tempered Greedy Token to make sure we haven't two “Reason for test” without “Pre-conditions Scenario” in between. But, for sure, your regex is working fine for the text given in example.